# Why can't I connect to an IBMQ device?

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I was trying the qiskit Terra [tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/9e3b1faacaa529208e615f5e5ef239c3fe610d34/qiskit/basics/getting_started_with_qiskit_terra.ipynb) and it seems that the code provided to connect to an actual quantum computer doesn't run properly. With my API token generated and stored into the variable "my_token", I typed :

```
IBMQ.save_account(my_token)
IBMQ.load_accounts()
```

and got the following error message :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-7eeefb4c8c69> in <module>()
----> 1 IBMQ.save_account(my_token)
      2 IBMQ.load_accounts()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqprovider.py in save_account(self, token, url, overwrite, **kwargs)
    134         """
    135         credentials = Credentials(token, url, **kwargs)
--> 136         store_credentials(credentials, overwrite=overwrite)
    137 
    138     def active_accounts(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/credentials/_configrc.py in store_credentials(credentials, overwrite, filename)
    122     # Read the current providers stored in the configuration file.
    123     filename = filename or DEFAULT_QISKITRC_FILE
--> 124     stored_credentials = read_credentials_from_qiskitrc(filename)
    125 
    126     # Check if duplicated credentials are already stored. By convention,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/credentials/_configrc.py in read_credentials_from_qiskitrc(filename)
     61         if 'verify' in single_credentials.keys():
     62             single_credentials['verify'] = bool(single_credentials['verify'])
---> 63         new_credentials = Credentials(**single_credentials)
     64         credentials_dict[new_credentials.unique_id()] = new_credentials
     65 

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'
```

Please tell me where I got it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce your issue by changing the key a few times... seems to be a bug.

Either way, I was able to resolve my issue by removing the `qiskitrc` file.

`rm ~/.qiskit/qiskitrc` (your location may vary)

After that, set the key again and you should be good.